# How to bind data in an adapter on a seperate thread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have inner classes `ViewHolder` and `StringHolder` in my custon adapter class

```
private class StringHolder {
    String awards; String countries; String directors; String fullPlot; String genres; String ID;
    String imdbRating; String imdbVotes; String lastUpdated; String languages; String metacritic;
    String posterUrl; String shortPlot; String rating; String releaseDate; String runtime; String writers;
    String title; String imdbId; String cast;
    public StringHolder(Cursor cursor){
        awards = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Awards"));
        countries = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Country"));
        directors = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Director"));
        fullPlot = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FullPlot"));
        genres = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Genre"));
        ID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID"));
        imdbRating = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imdbRating"));
        imdbVotes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imdbVotes"));
        lastUpdated = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("lastUpdated"));
        languages = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Language"));
        metacritic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Metacritic"));
        posterUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Poster"));
        shortPlot = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Plot"));
        rating = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Rating"));
        releaseDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Released"));
        runtime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Runtime"));
        writers = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Writer"));
        title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Title"));
        imdbId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imdbID"));
        cast = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Actors"));

    }
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView cast; TextView title; TextView plot; TextView imdbratings; TextView votes;
    ImageView bookmark; ImageView share; ImageView IMDBProfile; FlowLayout flowLayout;
    TextView releaseDate; TextView directors; TextView countries; TextView genres;
    public ViewHolder(View view){
        genres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genres);
        countries = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countries);
        directors = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.directors);
        releaseDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.releaseDate);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        plot = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.plot);
        imdbratings = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        votes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.votes);
        flowLayout = (FlowLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.hash_tag_layout);
        bookmark = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bookmark);
        share = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.share);
        IMDBProfile = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.IMDBProfile);
        cast = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cast);
    }
}
```

I set the strings from `StringHolder` (queried from my database) to the text views in `ViewHolder` in the `bindView` method of my cusotm adapter

```
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    // Get recycled viewHolder
    final ViewHolder viewHolder  =   (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    // Bind strings to views in viewHolder
    StringHolder stringHolder = new StringHolder(cursor);
    viewHolder.title.setText(stringHolder.title);
    viewHolder.plot.setText(parsePlot(stringHolder.shortPlot, stringHolder.fullPlot));
    viewHolder.imdbratings.setText(stringHolder.imdbRating + "/10");
    viewHolder.votes.setText(formatNumbers(stringHolder.imdbVotes));
    viewHolder.countries.setText(stringHolder.countries);
    viewHolder.directors.setText(stringHolder.directors);
    viewHolder.releaseDate.setText(parseDate(stringHolder.releaseDate));
    viewHolder.genres.setText(stringHolder.genres);
    viewHolder.cast.setText(stringHolder.cast);

}
```

The problem is my main thread is doing a huge amound of work and skipping frames. I tried binding the views in a new thread like so

```
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    // Get recycled viewHolder
    final ViewHolder viewHolder  =   (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    // Bind strings to views in viewHolder
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            StringHolder stringHolder = new StringHolder(cursor);
            viewHolder.title.setText(stringHolder.title);
            viewHolder.plot.setText(parsePlot(stringHolder.shortPlot, stringHolder.fullPlot));
            viewHolder.imdbratings.setText(stringHolder.imdbRating + "/10");
            viewHolder.votes.setText(formatNumbers(stringHolder.imdbVotes));
            viewHolder.countries.setText(stringHolder.countries);
            viewHolder.directors.setText(stringHolder.directors);
            viewHolder.releaseDate.setText(parseDate(stringHolder.releaseDate));
            viewHolder.genres.setText(stringHolder.genres);
            viewHolder.cast.setText(stringHolder.cast);

        }
    }.start();

}
```

Now I get this error

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Any idea how to fix the error while maintaing the extra work in a seperate thread?

**edit:**

Here is my `newView` method

```
// Apply recycling to a view container
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Your database cursor schema seems very, very "flat"... Did you join a bunch of columns together? Certainly a more "relational, nested" architecture would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Its not good idea to move the whole  view binding on different thread. seting text to view is not expensive operation creating the StringHolder is. You can
[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to read form the cursor in the doInBackground method, then onPostExecute, which is run on UI thread, you can set values to your views

Answer (score 0):

use runOnUiThread()

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        StringHolder stringHolder = new StringHolder(cursor);
        viewHolder.title.setText(stringHolder.title);
        viewHolder.plot.setText(parsePlot(stringHolder.shortPlot,stringHolder.fullPlot));
        viewHolder.imdbratings.setText(stringHolder.imdbRating + "/10");
        viewHolder.votes.setText(formatNumbers(stringHolder.imdbVotes));
        viewHolder.countries.setText(stringHolder.countries);
        viewHolder.directors.setText(stringHolder.directors);
        viewHolder.releaseDate.setText(parseDate(stringHolder.releaseDate));
        viewHolder.genres.setText(stringHolder.genres);
        viewHolder.cast.setText(stringHolder.cast);               
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably need to [do it like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152355/runonuithreadnew-runnable-is-undefined-for-the-type-new-thread)

Comment: What will be the point to go to another thread, just to run the task on the UI thread again?